# Gadfly.jl Display Actual Values on Chart

Tags: julia, gadfly

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to display the underlying data points on a Gadfly chart. I know that I can display the labels associated with a particular point, but how can I show the actual values on the chart, itself?

For example, from the Gadfly documentation, let's say I have this chart:

```
plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10))
```

How can I display the resulting values in the x and y vectors on the chart itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's easy to get a string representation, e.g. `string(3)`.

How about the following:

```
using Gadfly

N = 10
xx = rand(1:10, N)  # N random integers between 1 and 10
yy = rand(1:10, N)

labels = map(string, zip(x,y))

plot(x=xx, y=yy, label=labels, Geom.label, Geom.point)
```

This gives something like the following:

[image: points labelled by coordinates]

Comment: Cool, thank you. I forgot about map(). It's perfect here.

Comment: I was doing too much work: `labels = map(string, zip(xx, yy))`!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to feed the values into Gadfly via a labels string vector:

```
label_vec = ["4", "4", "7", "7", "9", "1", "8", "10", "11", "2"]

plot(x=rand(10), y=rand(10), Labels = label_vec, Geom.label)
```

It's a pain to parse ints/floats into strings though, it would be nice if you could feed them directly into Gadfly as ints/floats.

Does anyone have a better way?